# Ensure that a user selects a value in the dropdown on submission when using Odoo html form builder

Tags: html, validation, drop-down-menu, odoo, formbuilder

I have a dropdown in my form which was generated by the html form builder:

```
<select class="form-control">
    <option value="" selected="1" disabled="1">Select option</option>
    <option value="course 1">course 1</option>
    <option value="course 2">course 2</option>
    <option value="course 3">course 3</option>
</select>
```

Is there a simple way to ensure that the user selects a value in the dropdown before submitting the form? If he has not selected anything, then display an error message.

Also, I have an input field:

```
<div class="form-group field-x_street_name_1">
    <label for="x_street_name_1" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label col-form-label-lg">Street 1 <span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
       <input type="text" name="x_street_name_1" t-att-value="x_street_name_1" id="x_street_name_1" class="form-control form-control-lg" placeholder="e.g. John Lane" required="required" t-att-readonly="'readonly' if only_passwords else None" t-att-autofocus="'autofocus' if login and not only_passwords else None"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to ensure the user enters only between 10 to 30 uppercase, lowercase alphabets. I would ensure that using `html pattern` simply. But it does not seem to work.

Comment: Would the `required` attribute work?

Comment: yep `required` attribute is nice. But if you want advance functionality you can use Jquery or javascript  based Validation library. 
just google it "jQuery form Validation"

Comment: Neither JavaScript nor jQuery were tagged here, but validating this with JS is a simple matter of checking `if(!this.querySelector(".form-control").value){ /* show error message and prevent form submission here */ }` within a `submit` event listener bound to the `<form>`. To prevent form submission, call the `preventDefault` method on the event argument.

Comment: I forgot to mention when using Odoo html form builder. It already has some kind of validation. But I want to add like html patterns and all. Which does not seem to work.